Non-extendible manifold that is not geodesically complete
I am studying do Carmo's textbook on Riemannian geometry and in chapter 7.2 he proves Hopf-Rinow theorem. He begins the chapter by saying that we want to study geodesical completeness because we want to study global differential geometry. Then he defines extendible manifolds, as follows:

Which, in my point of view, should be the object we would study if we want to extend our local properties. But then he says that this definition is not good enough. My question is: why not? The book then proves that geodesically completeness imply that the manifold is non-extendible.

Could anyone give me an intuition of why extendible manifolds are "not enough" to study "global properties".
Thanks :)

It might help if you'd include the definitions of the terms you are talking about. Not everyone owns a copy of do Carmo's textbook (believe it or not). Specifially the term extendible manifold is not known to me (despite the fact that I was quite deep into differential geometry when I still worked on the topic)

Various forms of this question have been asked several times, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363798/example-of-a-non-complete-connected-non-extendable-riemannian-manifold-with-mi
